# Cannot use import declarations in modules

Tags: npm, import

I saw this run when i npm run build.Please guide me the proper solution                                                                     [eslint]
src/App.js
Line 1:1:    Cannot use import declarations in modules that export using CommonJS (module.exports = 'foo' or exports.bar = 'hi')  import/no-import-module-exports
Line 2:1:    Cannot use import declarations in modules that export using CommonJS (module.exports = 'foo' or exports.bar = 'hi')  import/no-import-module-exports
Line 3:1:    Cannot use import declarations in modules that export using CommonJS (module.exports = 'foo' or exports.bar = 'hi')  import/no-import-module-exports
Line 5:1:    Cannot use import declarations in modules that export using CommonJS (module.exports = 'foo' or exports.bar = 'hi')  import/no-import-module-exports
Line 6:1:    Cannot use import declarations in modules that export using CommonJS (module.exports = 'foo' or exports.bar = 'hi')  import/no-import-module-exports
Line 7:1:    Cannot use import declarations in modules that export using CommonJS (module.exports = 'foo' or exports.bar = 'hi')  import/no-import-module-exports
Line 12:28:  Delete `·`